# Using `eval(parse())` with a multiple elements vector

Tags: r, parsing, expression, eval

I'm trying to `eval(parse())` variable names from a character vector, but `eval()` returns only the content of the last variable:

My code:

```
c <- c(1,1)
a <- c(1,0)
t <- c(0,1)
g <- c(0,0)

sequence <- c("a", "t", "g", "t", "g", "t", "a", "c")
eval(parse(text=sequence))
```

It should return:

> `[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1`

But it just returns the correspondent to the last element of the vector: `c`

> `[1] 1 1`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mget` to get all the object values in a `list`, then `unlist` the `list` to create a `vector`

```
unlist(mget(sequence), use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

---

With `eval(parse`, it requires a `length` of 1.  We can loop over the `sequence` and do the `eval` (not recommended)

```
c(sapply(sequence, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
#[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: I definitely like the first way. I guess my question (more for the OP, not you) is whether the objects should simply be in a `list()` in the first place.

Comment: @Adam It is possible that the OP is new to `R` and when you are new, it is difficult to follow how the `list` works.  So, they create objects in the global env.

Comment: @akrun is absolutely right! ;) @Adam the object is a vector in a list. It's the ```Value``` of the function ```readfasta``` from the package ```seqinr``` .

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I can do it with:

```
bin <- NULL
for(n in 1:length(sequence)) {
  bin <- append(bin, eval(parse(text=sequence[n])))
  }
```

But I wonder if is there an easier way to do it without the for loop.